# MediaPlayer throws error (1, 22) Unable to play media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm doing a tutorial screen with several videos inside a viewPager, the problem is that in a Samsung Galaxy Fame

> 07-22 18:24:18.787: E/MediaPlayer(11724): Error (1,-22)
>   07-22 18:24:18.787: E/com.unipagos.app.tutorial.TutorialPagerAdapter$1$2@41bbce88(11724): Unable to play media

The code I'm using to play the videos and that works in other devices is this:

```
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface,
    int width, int height) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Surface s = new Surface(surface);
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayers.put(new Integer(position), mMediaPlayer);
try {
    String path = "tutorialvideos/" + tutorialPageItem.getMediaURL();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(path);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
    mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        private int videoPosition;

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            // close the progress bar and play the video
            //if we have a position on savedInstanceState, the video playback should start from here
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(videoPosition);
            if (videoPosition == 0) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } else {
                //if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will be paused
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
    });
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(
                MediaPlayer paramMediaPlayer,
                int what, int extra) {
            String message = "Unknown error";
            switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                message = "Unable to play media";

                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                message = "Server failed";

                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                message = "Invalid media";

                break;
            }
            Log.e("" + this, message);
            return false;
        }

    });
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can't find any information on that error code, but I've been told that it might be because of the codec it was used to make the video.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u solve this?

Comment: Did someone solve this?